# Where are JMS messages stored in WebLogic 9.2 server?

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, weblogic9.x

I would like to know at what location WebLogic 9.2 server stores JMS messages on disk.

Regards
Chaitanya

Comment: Thank you Superfilin. I am never aware of this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually highly depends on your configuration. Check *config* directory in your domain and search for JMSFileStore (I assume you are using that) configurations. **[Here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/domain_jmsfilestore_config.html)** is a little documentation about that.